# Cordova fb/google plugin wp8

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, cordova-plugins

I am developing cordova windows app.
I need solution to add facebook and google login to my app.
If any one knows, please provide steps to integrate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be by adding plugins to your app. Here are a couple I found on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/) (note that there are others out there -- this was just a cursory search):

- [cordova-plugin-facebook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook)
- [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-googleplus)

Instructions on how to install and use these plugins can be found at the links above. Generally to install a plugin, it's a call to:

```
cordova plugin add <pluginid> --save
```

This adds the plugin to your app (you have to be in that app directory for the call to work), and adds a line to your `config.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks for the post.
The plugins which you mentioned above are given for ios and android. But i need for wp8. Is there any other plugin available for wp8

Comment: If any one how to implement social login please let me know.